# Is it necessary to create both application-context.xml and application-servlet.xml in a single application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

- Why do we require a application-servlet.xml at all ?
- Why is application-context.xml alone insufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separation of concerns is just a best practice. No fire will suddenly appear if you ignore it, but you will have harder to maintain code. And if you carefully design your application with a web layer a service layer and a persistence layer, storing the beans in the proper application context will just make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It not necessary but recommended. Using separated configuration files you can isolate the `web` from the other world for security reasons(e.g. more secure).  You can make a spring-boot program even without a single configuration file by annotations.

The `application` context is a bigger context, it means the beans defined in this context can be referred by `servlet` context but not vice versa.